# ES6: class autoloading like PHP?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I've found yesterday on API-Docs of Webkit and Moz the implementation of ES6 the Class definition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

It's working fine on `node-webkit` and i like it!

For example i had write sample classes for database endpoints:

**Database.js**

```
class Database {
    construct() {

    }
}
```

**SQLite3.js**

```
class SQLite3 extends Database {
    construct() {

    }
}
```

**MySQL.js**

```
class MySQL extends Database {
    construct() {

    }
}
```

My question is, how to create an autoload feature of classes like `PHP`. I don't want to include the JavaScript files manually, the best solution is, to load needed classes on the fly.

But it is possible?

Comment: Thanks @georg for fixing :)

Comment: Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxy-autoload, to see how they're doing it

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `constructor`, not `construct`?

Comment: I guess there's a difference of opinion about what the _best solution_ is :D

Comment: @MadaraUchiha what's that comment supposed to mean exactly? We're allowed to bash whatever we want here, especially if we're moderators or did I get it wrong?

Comment: @Mjh It means that I provided information about Proxies being slow, and took a playful jab at PHP at the same time.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - here's something potentially "funny" - today, I had a nice chat with a junior developer who mentioned this very post as an argument for his decision that PHP autoloading, and PHP itself, is slow therefore he won't learn it. That's the extent of influence of moderators and high reputation members. Now, we could debate to infinity and beyond about PHP, performance etc. but in the end whatever language we use, we deliver finished products. My comment is here to highlight, even though "jokingly", you had pretty sever bad effect on someone. Food for thought, nothing else.

Comment: @Mjh you should totally start a thread about it on Meta. This badmouthing of PHP by these modraters cannot go undiscussed!

Comment: @Mjh +1 on starting a meta thread, time to make SO great again.

Comment: @DaveRandom - I agree with you 100% completely. And yes, it says much more about the person who read the comment than the guy who made it, I agree. But, if I learned anything, people do actively *seek* comments or opinions which they can use to justify what they want to believe. I know that kid in question doesn't want to do PHP but JS, however salaries aren't getting paid if you type JS code that interests you instead of PHP code that's needed in 30 minutes, which solves an actual problem the client has (no, junior didn't deal with production). Influencers need to be aware of their *power*.

Comment: @Mjh No, more like anyone can bash PHP, including moderators. As long as you're [Being Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) (and, y'know, not spamming, etc.) and it's relevant to the post, you can comment anything. That right is extended to moderators as much as anyone else. You're right, though, that mods should be careful in what they say, since some people wrongly associate ♦ with expertise in everything.

Comment: Guys, PHP is not the question! PHP was mention as example. It's not the question if PHP is slow or not. I want practices for automatic class loading and not a discuss if PHP is slow, slower or the slowest option in this world.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss

Have you found any?
I'm starting to think about writing my own composer like for node js that creates a classmap...

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `Dynamic Import()` of Javacript to add only required necessary class when needed.

As I am typing this answer from mobile se cannot go with a long code example, i hope you can implement easily.

Read this for more

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports